# Change specific dynamically created table row html and text from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

From the database, I have a dynamic table like this:

```
<table>
    <?php
    $query = ....;
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . ' <span class="bName">' . $row['brand_name'] . '</span>'.
        '<input name="product_id" type="number" value="' . $row['product_id'] . '">'.
        '<input name="company_id[]" type="number" value="' . $row['company_id'] . '">'.
        '<button name="exchange" type="button">Click Me!</button></td>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

It returns say 4 rows with `brand_name` inside the `<span>` and `product_id` inside an `<input>`. The `exchange` button on click calls an ajax request that query another random brand_name and returns the query as `JSON` like this:

```
{product_id: '2206', brand_name: 'New name', company_id: '234' }
```

The script for ajax is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[name="exchange"]').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxChangeBrand.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).parent().find('input[name="product_id"]').val(),
                success: function(response) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    $('.bName').html(data.brand_name); // Problem is here
                    $('.company_id').html(data.company_id); // and here
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My target is to change the `brand_name` inside class `bName` and `company_id` value with the new values from ajax response for that specific row. But my problem is it changes all the spans with `bName` class and all the inputs with class `company_id`. What should be the best approach to change the specific row of that table from the ajax data?

Comment: Seems to be a stray closing `</div>` that doesn't have an opening `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl yap, removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to the cell that the button that was actually clicked exists in so you can find within that cell the specific elements.

Also note that the company_id value is in an input thaat you ned to use `val()` on and you need to give it a class name

```
$('button[name="exchange"]').click(function() {
  // cell this button instance is in
  const $cell = $(this).closest('td');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxChangeBrand.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'keyword=' + $(this).parent().find('input[name="product_id"]').val(),
    success: function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      $cell.find('.bName').html(data.brand_name); // Problem is here
      $cell.find('.company_id').val(data.company_id); // and here
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks like a clean solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to test using AJAX but perhaps this might help. Use the `event` of the click function to find the parentNode and from that use `querySelector` to target the particular elements in the table row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="exchange"]').click(function(e) {
    let tr=e.target.parentNode;
    let span=tr.querySelector('span.bName');
    let pid=tr.querySelector('input[name="product_id"]');
    let cid=tr.querySelector('input[name="company_id[]"]');
    
    console.info( span.textContent, cid.value, pid.value)

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajaxChangeBrand.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).parent().find('input[name="product_id"]').val(),
      success: function(response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        span.textContent=data.brand_name;
        cid.value=data.company_id;
        pid.value=data.product_id;
      },
    });
    
    
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="bName">Womble</span>
      <input name="product_id" type="number" value="23">
      <input name="company_id[]" type="number" value="88">
      <button name="exchange" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="bName">Bagpuss</span>
      <input name="product_id" type="number" value="39">
      <input name="company_id[]" type="number" value="12">
      <button name="exchange" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="bName">Clanger</span>
      <input name="product_id" type="number" value="47">
      <input name="company_id[]" type="number" value="91">
      <button name="exchange" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My pleasure @Ashonko - good luck with the rest of your coding adventure!